# Expand() method doesn't bind all Data to the object

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I'm trying to query a WCF Data Service with oData. Everything works fine, but in a many to many relation the expand Function doesn't work. The Relation is: `Product 1-* ProductOrder *-1 Order`  Here is my code to query the service:

```
var queryProductOrder = (DataServiceQuery<ProductOrder>)SessionHelper.context.ProductOrder.Expand(x=>x.Product);
var allProductOrders = await queryProductOrder.ExecuteAsync();
```

If I run this in debug mode and check the allProductOrder Object, there is no Product. The interesting fact is, that when I check the generated OData Query and run it over the browser, the Product gets expanded.

The query looks like this:

```
http://localhost:10000/ProductOrder()?$expand=Product
```

And the JSON-Result is expanded:

```
{"odata.metadata":"http://localhost:10000/$metadata#ProductOrder","value":[{"Product":{"id":1,"Name":"Die Sims","Tax_fk":1,"Price":"44.99","Description":"Lebenssimulation","Stock":"99.00","TotalOrder":"0.00","ProductUnit_fk":1,"Barcode":"121212121","MainImage_fk":null,"Tenant_fk":1,"PurchasePrice":null},"id":1,"Product_fk":1,"Order_fk":1,"Tenant_fk":1,"Amount":"10"}]}
```

Also confusing is the fact, that on other many to many relations the expand method works like it should.

Why it doesn't expand the `allProductOrders` Object? Why is the `allProductOrders.First().Product` object `null` but the generated OData query returns the Expanded data?

Comment: Did you try changing the merge option? Try setting DataServiceContext.MergeOption to OverwriteChanges or PreserveChanges.

Comment: @Pratik: OverwriteChanges works! Maybe you can post it as a answer and descripe the difference. I allready read about it on msdn, but it might help others. I will mark your anwser as accepted then.